# How to configure VSCode on Mac so that backspace does not break undo coalescing?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In most Mac apps, a backspace does not break undo coalescing. For example in TextEdit, type "cat", hit backspace and then "r" to correct it to "car", and then hit cmd-z to Undo: the whole word is erased.

In VSCode a backspace does break undo coalescing. Try the above in VSCode and you will be left with "ca".

Is it possible to configure VSCode to work like other Mac apps in this respect?

Thank you for any help.